# Suitable Haskell type for large, frequently changing sequence of floats

Tags: haskell

I have to pick a type for a sequence of floats with 16K elements. The values will be updated frequently, potentially many times a second.

I've read the [wiki page on arrays](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays). Here are the conclusions I've drawn so far. (Please correct me if any of them are mistaken.)

1. IArrays would be unacceptably slow in this case, because they'd be copied on every change. With 16K floats in the array, that's 64KB of memory copied each time.
2. IOArrays could do the trick, as they can be modified without copying all the data. In my particular use case, doing all updates in the IO monad isn't a problem at all. But they're boxed, which means extra overhead, and that could add up with 16K elements.
3. IOUArrays seem like the perfect fit. Like IOArrays, they don't require a full copy on each change. But unlike IOArrays, they're unboxed, meaning they're basically the Haskell equivalent of a C array of floats. I realize they're strict. But I don't see that being an issue, because my application would never need to access anything less than the entire array.

Am I right to look to IOUArrays for this?

Also, suppose I later want to read or write the array from multiple threads. Will I have backed myself into a corner with IOUArrays? Or is the choice of IOUArrays totally orthogonal to the problem of concurrency? (I'm not yet familiar with the concurrency primitives in Haskell and how they interact with the IO monad.)

Comment: Have you tried http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix ?

Comment: No, but it appears to be mostly about linear algebra. Are you thinking of Data.Packed? Would there be any reason to use that over the Vectors package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to benchmark of course (with [criterion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion)) or you might be interested in browsing some benchmarks I did e.g. [here](https://github.com/jberryman/chan-benchmarks/blob/master/reports/ghc-7.6/bench-single.arrays.html) (if that link works for you; broken for me).

The `vector` library is a nice interface (crazy understatement) over GHC's more primitive array types which you can get to more directly in the [`primitive` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive). As are the things in the standard `array` package; for instance an `IOUArray` is essentially a `MutableByteArray#`.

Unboxed mutable arrays are usually going to be the fastest, but you should compare them in your application to `IOArray` or the vector equivalent.

My advice would be:

- if you probably don't need concurrency first try a mutable unboxed `Vector` as Gabriel suggests
- if you know you will want concurrent updates (and feel a little brave) then first try a [`MutableArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.5.2.1/docs/Data-Primitive-Array.html) and then do atomic updates with [these functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/atomic-primops-0.6.0.5/docs/Data-Atomics.html#g:3) from the `atomic-primops` library. If you want fine-grained locking, this is your best choice. Of course concurrent reads will work fine on whatever array you choose.

It should also be theoretically possible to do concurrent updates on a `MutableByteArray` (equivalent to `IOUArray`) with those `atomic-primops` functions too, since a `Float` should always fit into a word (I think), but you'd have to do some research (or bug Ryan).

Also be aware of potential memory reordering issues when doing concurrency with the `atomic-primops` stuff, and help convince yourself with lots of tests; this is somewhat uncharted territory.

Answer (score 5):

A good rule of thumb is that you should almost always use [the `vector` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) instead of arrays.  In this case, you can use mutable vectors from [the `Data.Vector.Mutable` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html).

The key operations you'll want are `read` and `write` which let you mutably read from and write to the mutable vector.

Comment: Good to know. What are the advantages over the Vector library as opposed to arrays?

Comment: @Jarrett Vastly greater selection of functions and stream fusion.